# Bypassing Login Password without losing encrypted data?

Tags: encryption, passwords, login-screen, bypass

I've been asked to bypass a local user login screen for windows 10.

After some research I found this [video](https://youtu.be/pXUpmCf-kd8) with step-by-step instructions on how to turn the "ease of access" button into the "command prompt", which would let me remove or change the password.

In the beginning of the video, there is a warning that suggest not to use this method if you have encrypted files, since they will be deleted in the process.

1. How do I bypass a password without deleting encrypted files?
2. how would I know if there are encrypted files on a computer without getting passed the login screen?
3. I found this [list](https://williamhartz.medium.com/5-easy-ways-to-bypass-windows-10-admin-password-cfeda41958ca) with 5 ways to bypass a password, would anyone know if any of these methods won't delete encrypted files?

All help and insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The typical method of accessing an account you don't know the password to won't work if the profile contains encrypted files due to EFS.  If you change the password, outside of the mechanic that is offered once you log into the account, will make the files inaccessible.  **The only way to access the files is to type the current password for the profile.**  It's not actually possible to change the password of a user, as another user, you can only reset the password.  This of course comes with the obvious warning that encrypted files will be lost.

Comment: @Ramhound how would I know if there were any encrypted files that we're locked?

Comment: Take the drive out, put it in a Mac. Turn off 'ownership' & examine at leisure. Anything encrypted will appear to be garbage, anything else will be yours to do with what you will. [If you need to write to NTFS, you will need 3rd party support, but Macs can read without issue]. Macs don't give a monkey's about any permissions on a non-boot drive, you can just switch them off.

Comment: @user18660 - Isn’t this your system?  If it’s not your system ask the owner. If EFS was used then the only way NOT to lose the encrypted files is to login into the profile normally.  That’s the entire point of using EFS, some problems, don’t have multiple solutions

Comment: @Ramhound unfortunately this system isn't mine and the person who owns it doesn't know very much about computers

Comment: you might start here: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/77325-find-all-encrypted-files-windows-10-a.html